# You migrated my question from Serverfault to SuperUser.com. How do I read it?

Tags: support, stackoverflow, sffaq

I asked a question here this morning and got about 5 good responses right away.  I just came back to check in on it and it's marked Closed, Migrated to SuperUser.com.

There's even a link, but it just directs me to the "you can't use SuperUser.com" page.

How do I see the answers to my question?

Comment: belongs to http://meta.serverfault.com/ or meta meta..

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6650/is-there-a-faq-on-my-questions-was-migrated-what-next

Answer (score 6):

You must admit it's a bit silly to move stuff to a site in semi-closed beta.  Until the site is really live, it would be better to just treat it as if it doesn't exist, so questions that would otherwise be moved there should be closed instead.

Comment: unless you're trying to make sure that it will work as desired... yes, its a PITA for those that missed the post about the beta, but if the testing allows us to work out any issues now as opposed to later I'll deal with the hassle that the beta entails.

Comment: How about just **not deleting or moving the question**? Take a cold shower, and if you still can't help yourself, wait until after superuser actually opens, and then move it.

Answer (score 5):

See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/super-user-semi-private-beta-begins/ for getting in to SU, set up your account (don't forget to link them), and then you'll likely see why it was moved as well.

Comment: +1 for linking to the blog post rather than just posting the password here.

Answer (score 3):

When you're asked for a password at [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com), type

> ( see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/super-user-semi-private-beta-begins/ )

That should then let you sign in with OpenID

Comment: Just did.  The question is not associated with my user id.

Comment: Don't post the beta password here. Just link to the blog post.